# Linker errors while compiling MFC program

Tags: mfc, linker-errors

I am getting these linker errors while building how to solve these errors?

```
1>SettingsDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CRegistry::DeleteKey(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?DeleteKey@CRegistry@@QAEHPB_W@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CSettingsDlg::SaveSettings(void)" (?SaveSettings@CSettingsDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>SettingsDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CRegistry::PutStringValue(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?PutStringValue@CRegistry@@QAEHPB_W0@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CSettingsDlg::SaveSettings(void)" (?SaveSettings@CSettingsDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>VWScanConnector.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CRegistry::PutStringValue(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?PutStringValue@CRegistry@@QAEHPB_W0@Z)
1>SettingsDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CRegistry::PutWordValue(wchar_t const *,unsigned long)" (__imp_?PutWordValue@CRegistry@@QAEHPB_WK@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CSettingsDlg::SaveSettings(void)" (?SaveSettings@CSettingsDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>VWScanConnector.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CRegistry::PutWordValue(wchar_t const *,unsigned long)" (__imp_?PutWordValue@CRegistry@@QAEHPB_WK@Z)
1>SettingsDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CRegistry::SetWorkKey(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?SetWorkKey@CRegistry@@QAEHPB_W@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CSettingsDlg::SaveSettings(void)" (?SaveSettings@CSettingsDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>VWScanCon.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CRegistry::SetWorkKey(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?SetWorkKey@CRegistry@@QAEHPB_W@Z)
1>VWScanConnector.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CRegistry::SetWorkKey(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?SetWorkKey@CRegistry@@QAEHPB_W@Z)
1>SettingsDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > __thiscall CResCtrl::LoadStringW(unsigned int)" (__imp_?LoadStringW@CResCtrl@@QAE?AV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@I@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CSettingsDlg::SaveSettings(void)" (?SaveSettings@CSettingsDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>VWScanCon.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > __thiscall CResCtrl::LoadStringW(unsigned int)" (__imp_?LoadStringW@CResCtrl@@QAE?AV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@I@Z)
1>VWScanConnector.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > __thiscall CResCtrl::LoadStringW(unsigned int)" (__imp_?LoadStringW@CResCtrl@@QAE?AV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@I@Z)
1>SettingsDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CRegistry::GetStringValue(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?GetStringValue@CRegistry@@QAEHPB_WPA_W0@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CSettingsDlg::LoadSettings(void)" (?LoadSettings@CSettingsDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>VWScanConnector.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CRegistry::GetStringValue(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?GetStringValue@CRegistry@@QAEHPB_WPA_W0@Z)
1>SettingsDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CRegistry::GetWordValue(wchar_t const *,unsigned long *,unsigned long)" (__imp_?GetWordValue@CRegistry@@QAEHPB_WPAKK@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CSettingsDlg::LoadSettings(void)" (?LoadSettings@CSettingsDlg@@AAEXXZ)
1>VWScanConnector.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CRegistry::GetWordValue(wchar_t const *,unsigned long *,unsigned long)" (__imp_?GetWordValue@CRegistry@@QAEHPB_WPAKK@Z)
1>Viewer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall CLog::PrintLog(wchar_t const *,enum LOGTXTTYPE,long)" (__imp_?PrintLog@CLog@@QAEXPB_WW4LOGTXTTYPE@@J@Z) referenced in function "public: int __thiscall CViewer::DoBatchScan(void)" (?DoBatchScan@CViewer@@QAEHXZ)
1>VWScanConnector.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall CLog::PrintLog(wchar_t const *,enum LOGTXTTYPE,long)" (__imp_?PrintLog@CLog@@QAEXPB_WW4LOGTXTTYPE@@J@Z)
1>VWScanCon.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CRegistry::CreateKey(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?CreateKey@CRegistry@@QAEHPB_W@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall CVWScanConApp::InitInstance(void)" (?InitInstance@CVWScanConApp@@UAEHXZ)
1>VWScanCon.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CRegistry::Initialize(enum CALLERTYPE,struct HKEY__ *,wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?Initialize@CRegistry@@QAEHW4CALLERTYPE@@PAUHKEY__@@PB_W@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall CVWScanConApp::InitInstance(void)" (?InitInstance@CVWScanConApp@@UAEHXZ)
1>VWScanCon.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall CLog::Initialize(enum CALLERTYPE,wchar_t const *,int,unsigned long,unsigned long)" (__imp_?Initialize@CLog@@QAEXW4CALLERTYPE@@PB_WHKK@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall CVWScanConApp::InitInstance(void)" (?InitInstance@CVWScanConApp@@UAEHXZ)
1>VWScanConnector.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall CXMLManager::CXMLManager(class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >)" (__imp_??0CXMLManager@@QAE@V?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall CVWScanConnector::InterpretConnector(void)" (?InterpretConnector@CVWScanConnector@@UAEHXZ)
1>VWScanConnector.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > __thiscall CXMLManager::GetFolderPath(long)" (__imp_?GetFolderPath@CXMLManager@@QAE?AV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@J@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall CVWScanConnector::Refresh(long)" (?Refresh@CVWScanConnector@@UAEHJ@Z)
1>VWScanConnector.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > __thiscall CXMLManager::GetDocumentPath(long)" (__imp_?GetDocumentPath@CXMLManager@@QAE?AV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@J@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall CVWScanConnector::DeleteDocument(long)" (?DeleteDocument@CVWScanConnector@@UAEHJ@Z)
1>VWScanConnector.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > __thiscall CXMLManager::GetPagePath(long)" (__imp_?GetPagePath@CXMLManager@@QAE?AV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@J@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall CVWScanConnector::DeletePage(long,long)" (?DeletePage@CVWScanConnector@@UAEHJJ@Z)
1>VWScanConnector.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall CLog::SetLogParameters(wchar_t const *,int,unsigned long,unsigned long)" (__imp_?SetLogParameters@CLog@@QAEXPB_WHKK@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CVWScanConnector::SetTechLogPath(wchar_t const *,int)" (?SetTechLogPath@CVWScanConnector@@UAEXPB_WH@Z)
1>VWScanConnector.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall CRegistry::DeleteValue(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?DeleteValue@CRegistry@@QAEHPB_W@Z) referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CVWScanConnector::RemoveRegFolder(class CRegistry *,class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,unsigned long)" (?RemoveRegFolder@CVWScanConnector@@AAEHPAVCRegistry@@V?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@K@Z)
1>C:\Program Files\Contentverse Client\system\Scan.Con : fatal error LNK1120: 17 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Where is the `CRegistry` class defined ?

Comment: It was implemented in dll file

Comment: The you are not linking against the dll's .lib file.

Comment: The issue has been resolved Michael, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

As said by Michael Walz you need to link the dependent libraries and dlls to fix linker errors.

Inorder to do that in Visual Studio

**Right click** on the project->Select **Properties**->Click and expand **Configuration properties** ->Select **Linker** ->Under Linker select **Input** 
on the right hand side edit the **Additional Dependencies** field to add the path where your libs/dlls are located.

**Edit:**

Check [this](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwio_I-Hu6zXAhVSp6QKHfgKCeIQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fhelp%2F309801%2Fyou-may-receive-an-lnk2019-error-message-when-you-build-a-visual-c-200&usg=AOvVaw1zOZaEUrHnmRpzbKJFdcw-) out

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but i had a similar problem which was solved by doing this in the stdafx.h

```
template class __declspec(dllimport) CStringT<char, class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char, class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > >;
```

In your case, i am guessing

```
template class __declspec(dllimport) CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >
```

And maybe others depending on your error log...

Cheers

**Edit:**

Check [this](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwio_I-Hu6zXAhVSp6QKHfgKCeIQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fhelp%2F309801%2Fyou-may-receive-an-lnk2019-error-message-when-you-build-a-visual-c-200&usg=AOvVaw1zOZaEUrHnmRpzbKJFdcw-) out